# Are Iteratees safe for managing resources?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1, loops, resource-management

Suppose I were reading from an `InputStream`.

How I would normally do it:

```
val inputStream = ...
try {
    doStuff(inputStream)
} finally {
    inputStream.close()
}
```

Whether or not `doStuff` throws an exception, we will close the `InputStream`.

---

How I would do it with iteratees:

```
val inputStream ...
Enumerator.fromStream(inputStream)(Iteratee.foreach(doStuff))
```

Will the `InputStream` be closed (even if `doStuff` throws an exception)?

A little test:

```
val inputStream = new InputStream() { // returns 10, 9, ... 0, -1
    private var i = 10
    def read() = {
       i = math.max(0, i) - 1
       i
    }
    override def close() = println("closed") // looking for this
}
Enumerator.fromStream(inputStream)(Iteratee.foreach(a => 1 / 0)).onComplete(println)
```

We only see:

```
Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)
```

The stream was never closed. Replace `1 / 0` with `1 / 1` and you'll see that the stream closes.

Of course, I could maintain a reference to the original stream and close it in case of failure, but AFAIK the idea of using iteratees is creating composable iteration without having to do that.

---

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. Is there a way to use iteratees so the resources are always disposed correctly?

Comment: Note that this behavior changed in 2.2 (although it's still kind of weird). I've never really thought Play's iteratee implementation had a very good resource-management story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iteratees were specially designed for safe resource management. See the first sentence of the *[Iteratee IO: safe, practical, declarative input processing](http://okmij.org/ftp/Streams.html#iteratee)*:

> Iteratee IO is a style of incremental input processing with precise resource control.

The idea is that when your resource is only accessed through iteratees then the resource-owning code can tell exactly when the iteratee is finished with the resource and close it immediately. On the other hand, when iteration is managed manually (as with a traditional `InputStream`) the user of the resource is responsible for closing it. This can lead to leaks.

Saying that, there was a bug in Play 2.1 where `fromStream` didn't manage the closing of its underlying `InputStream`! This bug was fixed in Play 2.2.

You can see the [`fromStream` code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.2/framework/src/iteratees/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/Enumerator.scala#L545-L571) to see how the `Enumerator` was fixed by using `onDoneEnumerating` to close the resource when the iteratee is finished.

Comment: Oh good, I'm glad to here it was a bug, not a intentional or fundamental limitation :)